# Store CGImageRef in a NSDictionnary

Tags: macos, nsdictionary, cgimage

My app is using a set of CGImageRef and I am wondering how to store them in an NSMutableDictionary in order to avoid memory leakes (How to transform them into NSObject and how to CFRelease properly)

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this was answered here: [How do I create a mutable array of CGImageRefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392321/how-do-i-create-a-mutable-array-of-cgimagerefs)