# Problems with NSArray of CGImageRef's (but not on simulator!)

Tags: ios, nsarray, cgimageref

I am trying to put a few CGImageRefs into an NSArray. It works as it should on the simulator, but not on the device - it crashes at the point where I try to form the array with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1 error. I tried other things too, like starting with a mutable array but it doesn't work either. The result of typing bt in the console is

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x2403, 0x3a9b25b6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 22, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x86ea78f7)
frame #0: 0x3a9b25b6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 22
frame #1: 0x32a98b5e CoreFoundation`+[__NSArrayI __new:::] + 58
frame #2: 0x00042388 NameOfMyApp
```

So basically I have a number of images, of letters, and I have a number of layers representing positions in the word that should each cycle through them. For example, layer1 displays letterC, then letterF, then letterP etc, while layer2 displays some other sequence.

I thought I'd load each letter once...

```
CGImageRef letterH = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:letterHfilename].CGImage;
CGImageRef letterI = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:letterIfilename].CGImage;
```

...and put the CGImageRefs in an NSArray property, cast to id:

```
self.titleLetters = @[(__bridge id)letterH, (__bridge id)letterI;
```

I then later do

```
layerN.contents = self.titleLetters[i];
```

but more importantly I have to be able to put them (may times each) in ANOTHER array:

```
[contentsValuesArray addObject:self.titleLetters[j]];
```

and then use that array as the values of a keyFrameAnimation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* contentsAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
contentsAnim.values = contentsValuesArray;
```

All this works fine in the simulator, every time.

As I said, I tried some variations, and the only thing that seems to work is when I form a mutable array with just one letter-imageref in it, using arrayWithObject. Even then, it only works sometimes, and it crashes further down in my programme.

I seem to have read somewhere that the CGImageRefs are not retained, so that they may be released before I even get to use them. Since I began coding after ARC was introduced I know little about releasing, and since it has always worked on the simulator, I figured that didn't apply in my case.

Also, in this reply:

[How do I create a mutable array of CGImageRefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392321/how-do-i-create-a-mutable-array-of-cgimagerefs)

a person working on Cocoa Frameworks says that it should work although he doesn't give any specifics, so it might be implied.

Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

**EDIT SOLVED**
It seems that the problem was indeed that the imagerefs did not exist when I tried to add them to the array, and this was because they had been released already. Apparently they need to be retained using CGImageRetain. It now works, I just need to make sure they are released afterwards.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply work with the UIImages instead?

Comment: You never actually say (unless it's in that unnecessarily long final couple of paragraphs) what is actually failing and how.

Comment: @Hot Licks, I don't know what is failing, but as I said in the reasonably brief first paragraph it crashes when I try to do self.titleLetters = (array of bridged CGImageRefs). I just end up in this xcode view that looks like machine code or something, completely meaningless to me, and I can't find any human readable explanation.

Comment: @DarkDust, the reason is that I was under the impression that this would require more memory if I display the same image on several layers. Instead of just sort of pointing to the image, it would be copied. Also, I thought you had to use CGImageRef for the CALayer.contents property, no?

Comment: The additional cost of the `UIImage` class compared to the `CGImage` is probably very small. You usually assign the image once to your layer (`myLayer.content = myImage.CGImage;`) and then maybe never again. So I doubt it's even worth saving the images in the first place. We do `[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]` a _lot_ in our apps and since it is already caching it's usually fast and efficient. You are already violating an important principle: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil._ Don't try to out-smart the system until you know (by measuring) that it's causing problems.

Comment: What is the error message??

Comment: @HotLicks It highlights a line of machine code (?) and the message says THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1 address = xxxxx)

Comment: @DarkDust I do actually need to switch the contents, and rather often. In the most important case I have a number of buttons (=layers) with 4 different states, three of which are in common across all buttons. Animating the contents is simpler than crossfading different sublayers! But I will try with uiimage, thanks for the tip. From here it looks like I would be dealing with CGImage anyway, but I will try!

Comment: When it crashes, type `bt` in the debug console.  Copy the output (the stack trace) and paste it into your question.  That said, my guess is one of your image refs is null.  This would make the literal array constructor throw an exception.

Comment: @DarkDust, it seems I am already doing what you suggest, no? I do CGImageRef letterX = CLASS-METHOD, where CLASS-METHOD ends with    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath].CGImage The return type is CGImageRef, though, since CGImage doesn't exist!

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks, I did that and I hope it will help someone determine the cause of the problem. An imageref that is null seems reasonable, but then it could perhaps be the issue I mentioned, that CGImageRefs are released before I have time to use them. It didn't work to put the method call straight into the @[...] either, though.

Comment: @DarkDust Now the reason for not using UIImage is clear, I need to be able to put the imageref's in an array in a certain order:            [contentsValuesArray addObject:self.titleLetters[j]]; and then use that array as the value array for an animation         CAKeyframeAnimation* contentsAnim; 
        contentsAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
        contentsAnim.values = contentsValuesArray;

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint:  Click the breakpoint tab in the left column, click the `+` at the bottom, click "Add Exception Breakpoint", take the defaults.

Comment: @HotLicks I had already done that, I think that is why it shows me the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, but the line it breaks at is not objective C, it looks like gibberish: 0x3a9b25b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]

Comment: Look at your stack display and find the topmost Objective-C method.

Comment: The only thing remotely resembling an objective C method that I can find is "objc_msgSend", which is repeated several times on the right, as well as under Thread 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the imagerefs were being released before I even had time to use them. It  seems this happens straight away (at least on the device), unless they are retained using CGImageRetain.